# How to get the ordinal number of a book on a bookshelf?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, ordinals

I'm doing a programming project similar to the [Library of Babel](https://libraryofbabel.info/) and I need to find out the ordinal number of a book in a library.

- The library has $10$ rooms ($a$)
- Each room has $4$ walls ($b$)
- Each wall has $5$ shelves ($c$)
- Each shelve has $32$ books ($d$)

Now my question is: if I know what room ($a$), wall ($b$), shelve ($c$) and book on that shelf ($d$), **how would I find the ordinal number of that book in the library ($n$)?**

Also I want to know how to do it the other way around. **If I know the ordinal number ($n$), how would I find ($a$), ($b$),($c$) and ($d$)**?

It might seem like multiplying them together would work, but because of commutative properties of multiplying ($ab = ba$) I get some conflicts if we simply swap out (for ex.) the book ordinal number for the room number.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit for clarification:
The first book is in room 1, wall 1, self 1 and book number 1. The ordinal for that book is 1.

Comment: I suggest you look up how to find the memory location where an array element is stored.  Your books are elements in a four dimensional array.  You could also look by hand at a small 2d example and you might find some inspiration.  You have to specify which variable increases fastest and whether you start counting at 0 or 1.  Where is book 3?  Where is book 17?

Comment: For the first question it should just be $n = 640(a-1) + 160(b-1) + 32(c-1) + d$

Comment: @RossMillikan Unfortunately for me, I'm dealing with $10$^$1834097$ books, and I can't store them all in memory.

Comment: With $10$ rooms, $4$ walls per room, $5$ shelves per wall and $32$ books per shelve, you only can store $6400$ books. To store $10^{1834097}$ books you'll need a much larger library.

Comment: You don't have nearly that many books with the parameters you list.  There are only $6400$.   I didn't say you should store them all in memory, I just stated a problem that does the same computation you are looking at.

Comment: @celtschk I know, but it's just a general concept. If it work with 10 rooms it should work with $n$ rooms as well. At least mathematically. This is MathSE afterall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that all numbers start with $0$. That is, $a\in\{0,\ldots,9\}$, $b\in\{0,\ldots,3\}$, $c\in\{0,\ldots,4\}$ and $d\in\{0,\ldots,31\}$. Then one way to get an ordinal number is:
$$n=32(5(4a+b)+c)+d$$
The reverse direction is then:

- Divide $n$ by 32. The remainder is $d$.
- Divide the quotient from the previous step by $5$. The remainder is $c$.
- Divide the quotient from the previous step by $4$. The remainder is $b$.
- The quotient from the previous step is $a$.

To get the equivalent numbering for numbers starting at $1$, just subtract $1$ from each number before doing the calculation and at the end add $1$ to the result.

Comment: This does work for any number of rooms, right?

Comment: @Janekmuric: Yes.